# Need help translating azure recoveryservices powershell to .net azure resourcemanagement sDK calls

Tags: c#, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-resource-graph, azure-site-recovery

I made the following powershell script to restore a database from azure recovery services.
I now need to repeat this in c# using the Azure.ResourceManager SDK.

I have a hard time matching the various commandlets to the equivalent invocations in the SDK, it seems to be rather poorly documented and uses a different naming convention. Microsoft being microsoft also seems to change naming every minor version.

If anyone could tell met what the equivalent is of things like
Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -VaultId $vault.ID -FriendlyName "abcd"
in the .net azure resource management SDK....

The core of the script I made that I try to translate to c#:

```
function Restore-OTADatabaseFromAzure {
    param (
        [string] $SourceSqlInstanceName,
        [string] $SourceSqlAGName,
        [string] $SourceDatabaseName,
        [string] $NewDatabaseName,
        [string] $HaNode,
        [string] $DataPath,
        [string] $LogPath
    )

    try 

        Select-azSubscription -Subscription $subscription
        
        #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/vaults/get?view=rest-recoveryservices-2023-04-01&tabs=HTTP
        $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vaultName  -Verbose 
        #Write-Host "Vault: $($vault.ID)"

        #$Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -VaultId $vault.ID -FriendlyName "abcd"
        #Write-Host "Container: $($container.Name)"

        $backupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureWorkload -WorkloadType MSSQL -Name "SQLDataBase;$($SourceSqlAGName);$($SourceDatabaseName)" -VaultId $vault.ID  -ProtectionStatus Healthy

        $startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10).ToUniversalTime()
        $endDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
        $recoveryPoints = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $backupItem -VaultId $vault.ID -StartDate $startdate -EndDate $endDate
        $latestRecoveryPoint = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $backupItem -VaultId $vault.ID -RecoveryPointId $recoveryPoints[0].RecoveryPointId

        # Restoring Friendly name is case-sensitive
        $TargetContainer =  Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -VaultId $vault.ID -FriendlyName $HaNode.ToLower()

        #Write-Host "TagetContainer: $($TargetContainer.Name)" warning! case sensitive names
        $TargetInstance = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectableItem -WorkloadType MSSQL -ItemType SQLInstance -Name "sqlinstance;ota" -ServerName "servername..." -VaultId $vault.ID


        $recoveryconfig = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupWorkloadRecoveryConfig -RecoveryPoint $latestRecoveryPoint -TargetItem $TargetInstance -AlternateWorkloadRestore -VaultId $vault.ID -TargetContainer $TargetContainer 


        $recoveryconfig.targetPhysicalPath
        $recoveryconfig.RestoredDBName = $NewDatabaseName

        $recoveryconfig.targetPhysicalPath[0].TargetPath = "$($DataPath)$($NewDatabaseName).mdf"
        $recoveryconfig.targetPhysicalPath[1].TargetPath = "$($LogPath)\$($NewDatabaseName).ldf"


        $recoveryconfig | Format-List

        $recoveryconfig.targetPhysicalPath

        # run the actual restore.
        $RestoreJob = Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -WLRecoveryConfig $recoveryconfig -VaultId $vault.ID 

        do
        {
            $RestoreJob = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -JobId $RestoreJob.JobID -VaultId $vault.ID
            Write-Host "Restoring: $($RestoreJob.Status), $($RestoreJob.StartTime), $($RestoreJob.EndTime), $($RestoreJob.Duration), $($RestoreJob.Operation)"
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }
        while (($RestoreJob.Status -ne "Completed") -And ($RestoreJob.Status -ne "Failed"))

        if ($RestoreJob.Status -eq "Completed") {
            return $true
        }
        else {
            return $false
        }
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}
```

I made a start:

```
 // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new ClientCertificateCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            };

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential
            var clientCertCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientCertificate, options);


            ArmClient client = new ArmClient(clientCertCredential);

            SubscriptionResource subscription = client.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}"));
            ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
            ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync(resourceGroupName);


            //$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vaultName  -Verbose 
            RecoveryServicesVaultResource vault = await resourceGroup.GetRecoveryServicesVaultAsync(vaultName);
```

Just pointing to a proper example or such is fine to. I want to do the work, but I can't find the information I need.

Comment: Why do you need to convert?  They may be a better way of combining PS and c# code.

Comment: @jdweng, fair question, but not something I have influence over. fwiw: powershell is also very slow compared to other languages and not at all type-safe. And many other things are missing in powershell that better languages have.

Comment: Powershell is using Net Library, but isn't compiled so the parsing will be slower than c#.  But I disagree with the features.  PS is much better the c#.  Any you can always use c# libraries in PS.

Comment: @jdweng then I suggest you start making webservices and websites in powershell and such if you think powershell is so much better at everything... :) 
powershell is nice for sysadmins, not serious development work.
The point is mute though. The customer wants a c# webservice to do automatic restores. powershell is not an option, whatever you or I may think or want.

Comment: You can use a Powershell Class inside a c# application and use PS for the SysAdmin commands.  The SysAdmin commands in c# are not very well documented and in PS it is only a couple of instructions while in c# it can be very messy.

Comment: @jdweng No doubt you mean well, but you seem to be missing the part where I said this is a job a HAVE to do, according to SET specifications. If you order a fiat car en are supplied with a volvo you would not be satisfied to, despite both being fine cars. Same here. pure c# is an requirement of the customer. I will get it done and if needed the will pay me for a lot of hours of work. But it has to be done.

Comment: Can you use the Powershell Class?   Powsershell is part of System Management.  See : https://gist.github.com/TheWover/bd7e580b3cb10ab5447b4dc83013cc88.  You can load from GitHub.

Comment: Have you tried using Gemini or ChatGPT? It does translate the script, no idea if the code is right though

Answer (score -2):

My college System Engineering Teach said requirements come from two places 1) Specifications 2) Visions.  It is the job of a System Engineer to turn Visons into Specifications.

You are the System Engineer.  You have to work with your customer to turn his Visions into Specifications.

In my opinion "Written in c# is a Vision", not a Specification.  It doesn't specify what libraries you can use or not use.  Can you use libraries from Github?  Can you use 3rd party libraries?  c# is managed and runs slow.  So can you write code in c++ when necessary to meet speed requirements?  Can you use compiled Matlab dlls?

Written in c# also doesn't say if you can or cannot use Process Class to call executables and scripts.  Can you use BAT files?  Can you use Python?  It doesn't say the type of projects you can use.  Can you use Windows Forms?  Can you have more than one project?  Can you use WPF or ASP.Net?  Do you need to target CORE or can you use Net?  Do code need to be run by an ADMIN or can normal users run code?

Both c# and Powershell use Net/Core Libraries.  There is really no differences between written in c# and Powershell.  Many c# libraries are not well documented especially the ones that interface with Windows System Methods.  The equivalent Powershell are just wrappers that have well documented interfaces to the same methods as c#.

So why struggle interfacing with the c# libraries when you can do same in Powershell?

Comment: Sorry this really is a -1, it does not answer the question. It just pushes your vision of the world. I tried to explain on the comments you made, but you seem desperate to force the issue. If I could have this removed I would.

Comment: Sorry if you think I'm forcing the issue.I have 45 years of work experience.The only point I'm trying to make is your customer requirements of "The customer wants a c# webservice" is a little vague.I've been working with c# for 15 years and have been frustrated with a the little documentation on using OS features. It seems the wrappers that Microsoft wrote into PS get the information a lot easier. Microsoft has proprietary methods to tunnel through the OS which is not documented in c#, but get the info with little effort in PS. Translating Azure recovery services in c# is not going to be easy.

Comment: in previous comments I tried to make clear that the requirements, fair or not smart or not, efficient or not, of the customer are a C# .net framework only code using the .NET azure management SDK (REST calls). I have 20+ years of experience myself. I can disassemble the powershell if I need to. But I like to avoid that spend of time. Sometimes customers make specifications and no matter the experience or whatever they will not change those.

Comment: Agree.  I would still for debugging in this case try PS and see the results. It may give clue what you need to do for the SDK.   Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-11.1.0

Comment: @zu1b : Agree. I would still for debugging in this case try PS and see the results. It may give clue what you need to do for the SDK. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-11.1.0